# build paraview code source using CMake error

Tags: cmake, build, paraview

I'm trying to build the Paraview from source code using CMake. I did installed QT version 6.6.0 but while building the Paraview I got this error:

```
CMake Warning at VTK/CMake/vtkModule.cmake:4810 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake

  but it set Qt6_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6" is considered to be NOT
  FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Failed to find required Qt component "Core5Compat".

  Expected Config file at
  "C:/Qt/6.6.0/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Core5Compat/Qt6Core5CompatConfig.cmake"
  does NOT exist



  Configuring with --debug-find-pkg=Qt6Core5Compat might reveal details why
  the package was not found.

  Configuring with -DQT_DEBUG_FIND_PACKAGE=ON will print the values of some
  of the path variables that find_package uses to try and find the package.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Qt/Widgets/CMakeLists.txt:94 (vtk_module_find_package)


CMake Error at VTK/CMake/vtkModule.cmake:4816 (message):
  Could not find the Qt6 external dependency.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Qt/Widgets/CMakeLists.txt:94 (vtk_module_find_package).
```

How to handle that error?

I want to build the paraview code source in order to host it in a dockable window with c#.

Answer (score 0):

ParaView sadly does not officially support Qt6 for now ... (https://gitlab.kitware.com/paraview/paraview/-/blob/master/Documentation/dev/build.md#building)

That is why you need the Qt Core5 compat module (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore5-index.html).

Comment: thank you for you response , so please how can i get the Qt Core5 compat module so i can build the paraview code source with Qt version 6 (since the QT version 5 is no more available)..thank you in advance

Comment: Core5 compat module should be found as an option when installing qt6 (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore5-index.html). On linux, KDE provides patches for Qt5 so mainy distro still provides qt5 (https://community.kde.org/Qt5PatchCollection)